# Moving a unix socket file for nginx and gunicorn

Tags: unix, nginx, gunicorn

I am trying to update the location of a socket file for my nginx configuration and gunicorn.service files. I am trying to change it from My-Project/backend.sock to home/engineers/My-Project/backend.sock to maintain a consistency across my staging and public servers. I have created the backend.sock file in the desired location. When I try changing proxy_pass in my nginx configuration and/or the bind for my gunicorn.service file, I would get a 502 error when going to the domain. It's probably something simple, but I don't have much prior experience with these tools and I haven't found anything about this sort of thing specifically from all of my time googling. Could someone help me out on this one?

Comment: *I have created the backend.sock* How did you do that? Normally the process that's listening on the socket will do that when it binds to the filename.

Comment: I just made a new file called backend.sock. I tried using the bind command I have documented, but no change.

Comment: That bind command being sudo gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 main.wsgi:application